# java/Jboss multiple login module

Tags: java, jboss

i have to establish a new security. I've seen that i can use multiple login modules instead of multiple security domains. But i don't find how and when do i tell my java app which login module i should use?
Here is the kind of login module i use :

```
<login-module code="Database" flag="required">
    <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/jdbc/hrdb"/>
    <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select TRIM(CDPASS) from"/>
    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select TRIM(ROLES),'Roles' from/>
    <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
</login-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of point of view the application you can only configure de security domain that it used.
When you stacking `LoginModules` (configure multiple login modules), you can specify the importance of such a module within the context of the stack.

For example: If you configure a LDAP `LoginModule` flagged `required` and the Database is flagged `sufficient` 
then LDAP login module must be succeed and Database can be succeeds and when Database module is succeeds the login process is completed.

The list below explains the semantics of each flag:

- **required**: The module must succeed; Login process will always
  continue
- **requisite**: The module must succeed otherwise login process
  fails
- **sufficient**: When module succeeds, login process is completed
- **optional**: Login process will continue regardless of the outcome

Comment: So i could create a generic user for the required module and then proceed the optional module with the real user id?

Comment: For each login module in a domain this captures user supplied login information (username and password for example) in the login method.